# Using Suspense component in vue 3 along with Options API

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, vuejs3, vue-options-api

The docs https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html#async-components says in order to use Suspense Components, we need to make the components "Asynchronous".

```html
<script setup>
const res = await fetch(...)
const posts = await res.json()
</script>

<template>
  {{ posts }}
</template>
```

But I am not sure how to make components Async using Options API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Options API, the component is made an *async* component by using an [`async setup()`](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html#async-setup):

```js
export default {
    
  async setup() {
    const res = await fetch(...)
    const posts = await res.json()
    return {
      posts
    }
  }
}
```

That's actually documented just above the docs section the question links to.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-async-components-options-api?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: @Tyler How does my answer contradict that? The `async setup()` hook is used in the Options API (vs `<script setup>`).

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation states, only `async setup` function and asynchronous `script setup` are supported. Options API is legacy and isn't supposed to receive new features.

As it can be seen in [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/9c304bfe7942a20264235865b4bb5f6e53fdee0d/packages/runtime-core/src/component.ts#L639-L670), only `setup` is supported.

It may be possible to access internal component instance and follow the way `setup` works, e.g.:

```
beforeCreate() {
  this.$.asyncDep = promise;
},
```

But this is undocumented and hacky way that can become broken without notice.